# Is it illegal to use the select key for plinking in major tournaments?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, competitive-gaming

In Street Fighter IV you can remap the Select key to be easily accessible so you can plink your light punch.

Is this "trick" legal or illegal on major tournaments?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on which tournament you go to?  Each one will have their own rules.

Comment: @Frank Virtually all major SF4 tournaments are part of the Evo tournament circuit and follow the Evo ruleset.

Comment: This question was not too broad. I find it ridiculous that 5 people who don't list a single fighting game as their favourite, much less participate in the fighting game community think they have the expertise to make this decision. There is most definitely only a small number of major tournaments, and those rule sets can be determined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, it is allowed.

The latest version of the [Evo 2014 ruleset](http://evo.shoryuken.com/f-a-q/) permits custom controllers and sticks, including Hitboxes and sticks with custom button layouts (including sticks with a Back/Select button on the top surface of the stick). The only things that are explicitly forbidden are wireless controllers, and the use of turbo functionality.

Most major regional tournaments in North America generally follow the Evo rules as well. For minor local tournaments and foreign tournaments, you'll need to ask the tournament organizer.

Comment: Op is in Germany, not the US.

Comment: That wasn't mentioned, so apologies. In any case, Evo is the largest tournament in the world, so its rulings can carry some weight, even overseas.

Comment: This question is only answerable by generalizatons, anyhow; if the OP would like to know about the rules of a specific tournament in his/her locality, the tournament organizer is the sole authority for that decision.

Comment: For me this is good enough. EVO rules are the unofficial standard.